# How to disable other keys on press of one key in custom keyboard?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-custom-keyboard

I want to disable press of other keys on press of some keys in my custom keyboard and i also want to disable touches on outside my custom keyboard because touching outside and holding some keys and pressing other keys automatically inserting characters in edittext.i want to stop that.

My CustomKeyBoardClass here

```
public class CustomKeyboard extends View {

    int touchPosition;
    int id;

    /**
     * A link to the KeyboardView that is used to render this CustomKeyboard.
     */
    private KeyboardView mKeyboardView;
    /**
     * A link to the activity that hosts the {@link #mKeyboardView}.
     */
    private AppCompatActivity mHostActivity;
    private Keyboard mKeyBoard;
    private View mInflater;
    Boolean longpressded=false;
    View custom = LayoutInflater.from(getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.kbpreview, new FrameLayout(getContext()));
    PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(this);


    /**
     * The key (code) handler.
     */
    private KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener mOnKeyboardActionListener = new KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener() {

        public final static int CodeDelete = -5; // Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE
        public final static int CodeCancel = -3; // Keyboard.KEYCODE_CANCEL
        public final static int CodePrev = 55000;
        public final static int CodeAllLeft = 55001;
        public final static int CodeLeft = 55002;
        public final static int CodeRight = 55003;
        public final static int CodeAllRight = 55004;
        public final static int CodeNext = 55005;
        public final static int CodeClear = 55006;

        public final static int CodeDone = 55007;
        public final static int CodeCaps = -1;
        public final static int QwertNumberKeypad = 1100;
        public final static int QwertNumericKeypad = 1101;
        public final static int CodeBackSpace = -4;
        private boolean caps = false;


        @Override
        public void onKey(final int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
            // NOTE We can say '<Key android:codes="49,50" ... >' in the xml
            // file; all codes come in keyCodes, the first in this list in
            // primaryCode
            // Get the EditText and its Editable

            View focusCurrent = mHostActivity.getWindow().getCurrentFocus();
            if (focusCurrent == null
                    || focusCurrent.getClass() != AppCompatEditText.class)
                return;
            final AppCompatEditText edittext = (AppCompatEditText) focusCurrent;

            edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                    String searchString = s.toString();
                    int textLength = searchString.length();
//                    edittext.setSelection(textLength);
                }

                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }

            });

            // System.out.println("print edit text id==="+edittext.getId());
            // if(edittext.getId()==R.id.ed_hack){
            //
            // // invisible the hack============fix it later
            // System.out.println("id matched");
            // //edittext.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            //
            // // make the layout visible==========
            //
            // mHostActivity.findViewById(R.id.ll_enter_id).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //
            // // Show the input field and focus on keypad
            // touched================
            // ((EditText)mHostActivity.findViewById(R.id.et_enter_id_landing)).requestFocus();
            //
            //
            // }

            Editable editables = edittext.getText();
            int start = edittext.getSelectionStart();
            int end = edittext.getSelectionEnd();

            // Apply the key to the edittext
            if (primaryCode == CodeCancel) {
                hideCustomKeyboard();
            } else if (primaryCode == CodeDelete) {
                if (editables != null && start > 0) {
                    editables.delete(start - 1, start);
                    edittext.setSelection(start - 1);
                }
            }



            /*
             * else if( primaryCode==CodeBackSpace ) { if( editable!=null && end
             * >0 ) editable.delete(end - 1, end); }
             */
            else if (primaryCode == CodeClear) {
                if (editables != null)
                    editables.clear();
            } else if (primaryCode == CodeLeft) {
                if (start > 0)
                    edittext.setSelection(start - 1);
            } else if (primaryCode == CodeRight) {
                if (start < edittext.length())
                    edittext.setSelection(start + 1);
            } else if (primaryCode == CodeAllLeft) {
                edittext.setSelection(0);
            } else if (primaryCode == CodeAllRight) {
                edittext.setSelection(edittext.length());
            } else if (primaryCode == CodePrev) {
                View focusNew = edittext.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_BACKWARD);
                if (focusNew != null)
                    focusNew.requestFocus();
            } else if (primaryCode == CodeNext) {
                View focusNew = edittext.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_FORWARD);
                if (focusNew != null)
                    focusNew.requestFocus();
            } else if (primaryCode == CodeDone) {
                hideCustomKeyboard();
            }

            // for capslock

            else if (primaryCode == CodeCaps) {
                caps = !caps;
                mKeyBoard.setShifted(caps);
                mKeyboardView.invalidateAllKeys();

//                edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS);
//
//                edittext.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new
//                        InputFilter.AllCaps()});

            } else { // insert character

                if (primaryCode != QwertNumericKeypad && primaryCode != QwertNumberKeypad ) {
                    char code = (char) primaryCode;
                    if (Character.isLetter(code) && caps) {
                        code = Character.toUpperCase(code);
                    }
                    editables.insert(start, Character.toString((char) code));
                }

            }
            Log.d("Gajanand", "onKey: at first" + caps);
            if (primaryCode == QwertNumberKeypad) {
                mKeyboardView.setKeyboard(new Keyboard(mHostActivity,
                        R.xml.qwerty));
                mKeyboardView.invalidateAllKeys();
                Log.d("Gajanand", "onKey:in number keypad " + caps);
            }
            if (primaryCode == QwertNumericKeypad) {
                mKeyboardView.setKeyboard(new Keyboard(mHostActivity,
                        R.xml.qwerty_numbers));
                mKeyboardView.invalidateAllKeys();
                Log.d("Gajanand", "onKey:in numeric keypad " + caps);
            }

            popup.setContentView(custom);

            mKeyboardView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        mKeyboardView.closing(); // Close popup keyboard if it's showing
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            });


        }

        @Override
        public void onPress(int arg0) {
            Log.d("Gajanand", "onPress:GK ");


        }

        @Override
        public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {
            Log.d("Gajanand", "onRelease: GK");

        }

        @Override
        public void onText(CharSequence text) {
        }

        @Override
        public void swipeDown() {
        }

        @Override
        public void swipeLeft() {
        }

        @Override
        public void swipeRight() {
        }

        @Override
        public void swipeUp() {
        }

    };

    /**
     * Create a custom keyboard, that uses the KeyboardView (with resource id
     * <var>viewid</var>) of the <var>host</var> activity, and load the keyboard
     * layout from xml file <var>layoutid</var> (see {@link Keyboard} for
     * description). Note that the <var>host</var> activity must have a
     * <var>KeyboardView</var> in its layout (typically aligned with the bottom
     * of the activity). Note that the keyboard layout xml file may include key
     * codes for navigation; see the constants in this class for their values.
     * Note that to enable EditText's to use this custom keyboard, call the
     * {@link #registerEditText(int)}.
     *
     * @param host     The hosting activity.
     * @param viewid   The id of the KeyboardView.
     * @param layoutid The id of the xml file containing the keyboard layout.
     */

    public CustomKeyboard(AppCompatActivity host, int viewid, int layoutid) {

        super(host);
        mHostActivity = host;
        mKeyboardView = (KeyboardView) mHostActivity.findViewById(viewid);
        mKeyBoard = new Keyboard(mHostActivity, layoutid);
        mKeyboardView.setKeyboard(mKeyBoard);
        mKeyboardView.setPreviewEnabled(false); // NOTE Do not show the preview
        // balloons
        mKeyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(mOnKeyboardActionListener);
        // Hide the standard keyboard initially
        mHostActivity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    }

//    @Override
//    protected void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd) {
//        super.onSelectionChanged(selStart, selEnd);
//
//        Log.d("Gajanand", "onSelectionChanged: yes changed");
//    }

    public CustomKeyboard(AppCompatActivity host, View inflater, int viewid, int layoutid) {
        super(host);
        mHostActivity = host;
        mInflater = inflater;
        mKeyboardView = (KeyboardView) mInflater.findViewById(viewid);

        mKeyBoard = new Keyboard(mHostActivity, layoutid);
        mKeyboardView.setKeyboard(mKeyBoard);
        mKeyboardView.setPreviewEnabled(true); // NOTE Do not show the preview
        // balloons
        mKeyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(mOnKeyboardActionListener);
        // Hide the standard keyboard initially
        mHostActivity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    }

    /**
     * Returns whether the CustomKeyboard is visible.
     */
    public boolean isCustomKeyboardVisible() {
        return mKeyboardView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
    }

    /**
     * Make the CustomKeyboard visible, and hide the system keyboard for view v.
     */
    public void showCustomKeyboard(View v) {
        mKeyboardView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mKeyboardView.setEnabled(true);
        if (v != null)
            ((InputMethodManager) mHostActivity
                    .getSystemService(AppCompatActivity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
                    .hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }

    /**
     * Make the CustomKeyboard invisible.
     */
    public void hideCustomKeyboard() {
        mKeyboardView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mKeyboardView.setEnabled(false);
        sendStatusToActivity("hide");
    }

    private void sendStatusToActivity(String msg) {

        Intent intent = new Intent("KEYPAD");
        intent.putExtra("Status", msg);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mHostActivity).sendBroadcast(intent);
//        stopservice();
    }

    /**
     * Register <var>EditText<var> with resource id <var>resid</var> (on the
     * hosting activity) for using this custom keyboard.
     *
     * @param resid The resource id of the EditText that registers to the custom
     *              keyboard.
     */
    public void registerEditText(int resid) {
        // Find the EditText 'resid'
        AppCompatEditText edittext;

        /*View focusCurrent = mHostActivity.getWindow().getCurrentFocus();
        if (focusCurrent == null
                || focusCurrent.getClass() != AppCompatEditText.class)
            return;
        final AppCompatEditText edittext = (AppCompatEditText) focusCurrent;*/

        edittext = (AppCompatEditText) mHostActivity.findViewById(resid);
        if (edittext == null) {
            edittext = (AppCompatEditText) mInflater.findViewById(resid);
        }

        // Make the custom keyboard appear
        edittext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            // NOTE By setting the on focus listener, we can show the custom
            // keyboard when the edit box gets focus, but also hide it when the
            // edit box loses focus
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

                if (hasFocus)
                    showCustomKeyboard(v);
                else
                    hideCustomKeyboard();
            }
        });
        edittext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            // NOTE By setting the on click listener, we can show the custom
            // keyboard again, by tapping on an edit box that already had focus
            // (but that had the keyboard hidden).
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("kishan", "onClick: keypad");
                showCustomKeyboard(v);
            }
        });
        // Disable standard keyboard hard way
        // NOTE There is also an easy way:
        // 'edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL)' (but you will not have a
        // cursor, and no 'edittext.setCursorVisible(true)' doesn't work )
        edittext.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Log.d("kishan", "onTouch: keypad");
                showCustomKeyboard(v);
                AppCompatEditText edittext = (AppCompatEditText) v;

                float x = event.getX();
                float y = event.getY();
                touchPosition = edittext.getOffsetForPosition(x, y);
                if (touchPosition > 0) {
                    edittext.setSelection(touchPosition);
                }

                int inType = edittext.getInputType(); // Backup the input type
                edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL); // Disable standard
                // keyboard
                edittext.onTouchEvent(event); // Call native handler
                edittext.setInputType(inType); // Restore input type
                return true; // Consume touch event
            }
        });
        // Disable spell check (hex strings look like words to Android)
        edittext.setInputType(edittext.getInputType()
                | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
    }

    public void registerAutoCompleteEditText(int resid) {
        // Find the EditText 'resid'
        System.out.println("hello ");
        AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView;

        autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) mHostActivity.findViewById(resid);
        if (autoCompleteTextView == null) {
            autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) mInflater.findViewById(resid);
        }

        System.out.println("hello 1");
        // Make the custom keyboard appear
        autoCompleteTextView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            // NOTE By setting the on focus listener, we can show the custom
            // keyboard when the edit box gets focus, but also hide it when the
            // edit box loses focus
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                System.out.println("hello 2");
                if (hasFocus)
                    showCustomKeyboard(v);
                else
                    hideCustomKeyboard();
            }
        });
        autoCompleteTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            // NOTE By setting the on click listener, we can show the custom
            // keyboard again, by tapping on an edit box that already had focus
            // (but that had the keyboard hidden).
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showCustomKeyboard(v);
            }
        });
        // Disable standard keyboard hard way
        // NOTE There is also an easy way:
        // 'edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL)' (but you will not have a
        // cursor, and no 'edittext.setCursorVisible(true)' doesn't work )
        autoCompleteTextView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                AutoCompleteTextView edittext = (AutoCompleteTextView) v;

                float x = event.getX();
                float y = event.getY();
                touchPosition = edittext.getOffsetForPosition(x, y);
                if (touchPosition > 0) {
                    edittext.setSelection(touchPosition);
                }

                int inType = edittext.getInputType(); // Backup the input type
                edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL); // Disable standard
                // keyboard
                edittext.onTouchEvent(event); // Call native handler
                edittext.setInputType(inType); // Restore input type
                return true; // Consume touch event
            }
        });
        // Disable spell check (hex strings look like words to Android)
        System.out.println("hello 5");
        autoCompleteTextView.setInputType(autoCompleteTextView.getInputType()
                | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
    }

}
```